# Stata query: Need help creating a new variable dependent on data from a different row within same household

Tags: stata

I want to create a new column in my cross-section survey dataset, that includes the education of a woman's husband. I have IDs of household (hid) and individual (HL1), and the following information:

- MA1== whether woman is married (data only observable for women)
- MA2== age of husband (data only observable for women who are married)
- HL4== sex (data observable for all individuals)
- HL6== age (data observable for all individuals)
- ED4A== highest level of education (data observable for all individuals)

In essence, I want to create code to do the following:

- First look at whether wife is currently married (MA1)
- If yes, then look at age of husband (MA2)
- Then pair age of husband (MA2) with age of male in household (HL6)
- Then see what that male's education is (ED4A) and put that education in a new column, but in the same row as the woman's line number.

I tried this but it doesn't work:
`bysort hid (HL6) : gen husb_educ = ED4A[MA2]`

Below is a sample from the dataset:

```
+-----+----------+-----+-----+--------+-----+----------+
| HL1 |   MA1    | MA2 | hid |  HL4   | HL6 |   ED4A   |
+-----+----------+-----+-----+--------+-----+----------+
|   1 |          |     | 106 | Male   |  57 | Diploma  |
|   2 |          |     | 106 | Female |  53 | Intermed |
|   3 |          |     | 106 | Male   |  30 | Higher S |
|   4 | No, not  |     | 106 | Female |  24 | Bachelor |
|   5 |          |     | 106 | Male   |  22 | Diploma  |
|   6 |          |     | 106 | Male   |  17 | Secondar |
|   7 |          |     | 106 | Female |  10 | Primary  |
|   8 | Yes, cur |  22 | 106 | Female |  23 | Diploma  |
|   9 |          |     | 106 | Female |   0 |          |
+-----+----------+-----+-----+--------+-----+----------+
```

So in this example, I want a new column which says Husband's education, and in row 8, puts Diploma as the value in the new column (since the woman's husband is 22years old, and the male 22 year old in the household has a diploma).

Same sample, without value labels:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| HL1 | MA1 | MA2 | hid | HL4 | HL6 | ED4A |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
|   1 |     |     | 106 |   1 |  57 |    4 |
|   2 |     |     | 106 |   2 |  53 |    2 |
|   3 |     |     | 106 |   1 |  30 |    6 |
|   4 |   3 |     | 106 |   2 |  24 |    5 |
|   5 |     |     | 106 |   1 |  22 |    4 |
|   6 |     |     | 106 |   1 |  17 |    3 |
|   7 |     |     | 106 |   2 |  10 |    1 |
|   8 |   1 |  22 | 106 |   2 |  23 |    4 |
|   9 |     |     | 106 |   2 |   0 |      |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
```

One especially large household:

```
    input
HL1 MA1 MA2 hid     HL4 HL6 ED4A
1   .   .   365809  1   33  1
2   1   33  365809  2   26  1
1   .   .   365810  1   58  1
2   .   .   365810  2   54  .
3   .   .   365810  1   23  3
4   .   .   365810  1   23  2
5   .   .   365810  1   18  3
6   .   .   365810  1   15  2
7   .   .   365810  2   12  2
8   .   .   365810  1   33  3
9   1   dk  365810  2   31  1
10  .   .   365810  2   13  2
11  .   .   365810  2   11  1
12  .   .   365810  1   9   1
13  .   .   365810  1   6   1
14  .   .   365810  2   3   .
15  .   .   365810  1   2   .
16  .   .   365810  1   33  3
17  1   33  365810  2   30  1
18  .   .   365810  1   8   1
19  .   .   365810  2   6   1
20  .   .   365810  2   5   .
21  .   .   365810  1   1   .
22  .   .   365810  1   32  4
23  1   32  365810  2   30  1
24  .   .   365810  1   5   .
25  .   .   365810  2   3   .
26  .   .   365810  1   2   .
27  .   .   365810  1   30  4
28  1   30  365810  2   28  1
29  .   .   365810  2   2   .
30  .   .   365810  1   0   .
31  .   .   365810  1   27  2
32  1   27  365810  2   27  1
33  .   .   365810  2   2   .
34  .   .   365810  2   0   .
         end
```

Comment: Suppose the husband is aged 42. Then you are asking for `ED4A[42]` within the current household. That will usually be missing and it's not what you want.

Comment: Give us a small sample of realistic data. Please don't ask us to imagine your data or make up our own example.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. In this dataset, ED4A refers to the highest level of education that the individual has achieved during their lifetime (most of the adults would have completed their education anyways). So for the 42 year old, ED4A may be secondary education, or diploma, or missing, for example. Apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: Evidently it was me who wasn't clear enough. I was asking for you to give us realistic data within your question. The definitions aren't the issue.

Comment: I have done the requested.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Presumably there could be two or more married women in each household: correct? What do you want to happen if there are two or more males in the same household with the same age as the husbands? What do you want to happen if there are two or more married women with the same age for their husbands?

Comment: My pleasure.
-There could be 2 or more married women in each house, correct. If these women all have the same husband (because there is only 1 man with that age recorded for the household), then I want all of these women to have the education of husband noted in the new column.
-If there are 2 or more males with the same age, I would like the response to be stored as a 9.
-If there are 2 or more married women with the same age for their husbands and more than 1 male with that same age, I would like the response to be stored as a 99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a start. The code does loop over different married women within each household, but it does nothing if two or more men match the husband's age.

```
input  HL1  MA1  MA2  hid  HL4  HL6  ED4A 
  1    .   .     106    1   57     4 
  2    .   .     106    2   53     2 
  3    .   .     106    1   30     6 
  4    3   .     106    2   24     5 
  5    .   .     106    1   22     4 
  6    .   .     106    1   17     3 
  7    .   .     106    2   10     1 
  8    1  22     106    2   23     4 
  9    .   .     106    2    0     .    
 end 

bysort hid (MA1) : gen wid = _n if MA1 == 1 

su wid, meanonly 

local max = r(max) 

gen heducation = . 

quietly forval i = 1/`max' { 
    bysort hid : egen hage = min(cond(wid == `i', MA2, .)) 
    by hid : egen nmatches = total(HL4 == 1 & HL6 == hage) 
    by hid : egen work = min(cond(nmatches == 1 & HL6 == hage, ED4, .)) 
    replace heducation = work if wid == `i' 
    drop hage nmatches work 
}

sort hid HL1 

list 

     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
     | HL1   MA1   MA2   hid   HL4   HL6   ED4A   wid   heduca~n |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   1     .     .   106     1    57      4     .          . |
  2. |   2     .     .   106     2    53      2     .          . |
  3. |   3     .     .   106     1    30      6     .          . |
  4. |   4     3     .   106     2    24      5     .          . |
  5. |   5     .     .   106     1    22      4     .          . |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |   6     .     .   106     1    17      3     .          . |
  7. |   7     .     .   106     2    10      1     .          . |
  8. |   8     1    22   106     2    23      4     1          4 |
  9. |   9     .     .   106     2     0      .     .          . |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

(UPDATE)

The extended example found a bug: one calculation was not restrictive enough by not excluding females with the same age. (Incidentally, note that the new data are for two households, not one.)

```
bysort hid (MA1) : gen wid = _n if MA1 == 1 

su wid, meanonly 

local max = r(max) 

gen heducation = . 

quietly forval i = 1/`max' { 
    bysort hid : egen hage`i' = min(cond(wid == `i', MA2, .)) 
    by hid : egen nmatches`i' = total(HL4 == 1 & HL6 == hage`i') 
    by hid : egen work`i' = min(cond(nmatches`i' == 1 & HL6 == hage`i' & HL4 == 1, ED4, .)) 
    replace heducation = work`i' if wid == `i' 
}

sort hid wid HL1 

    list hid wid MA2 HL6 ED4 heducation HL4 if inlist(HL6, 27, 30, 32, 33) | MA2 < ., sepby(hid) 

     +--------------------------------------------------+
     |    hid   wid   MA2   HL6   ED4A   heduca~n   HL4 |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 365809     1    33    26      1          1     2 |
  2. | 365809     .     .    33      1          .     1 |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  3. | 365810     1    27    27      1          2     2 |
  4. | 365810     2    33    30      1          .     2 |
  5. | 365810     3    32    30      1          4     2 |
  6. | 365810     4    30    28      1          4     2 |
 14. | 365810     .     .    33      3          .     1 |
 21. | 365810     .     .    33      3          .     1 |
 26. | 365810     .     .    32      4          .     1 |
 30. | 365810     .     .    30      4          .     1 |
 33. | 365810     .     .    27      2          .     1 |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

For more general discussions, see

[here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055) or [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0075) or [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-variables-recording-properties/).

Comment: Thank you very much for this! It has worked on many of the observations- however, some of them are showing odd results. I have edited the question's sample dataset to include one such household (a very big household) for which the results did not make sense.

Comment: Please give the extended data as reproducible `input` code. My answer shows you how.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have now edited it as reproducible input code.

Comment: Wow, that is beautiful. Thank you so very much for this!

Comment: Good. I added some references on technique.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already outlined the steps necessary to do what you want, writing a simple script for this should not be problematic. 
In my experience its easier to learn the syntax if you write/do each step separately (and see what happens after each step, if any error is introduced etc). After getting the hang of it, you can slim the code down to one line. Something like this should work (tried following the steps in your question):

```
*look at wife currently married
*not necessary, as only married women have MA2, but next step takes only married women into account

* generate husbands age variable and spread to whole household (new var to keep original MA2 untouched)
gen husband_age=MA2 if MA1==married & HL4==woman
bys hid: egen husband_age_hid=max(husband_age)

*mark which individual is the husband (assumed this is what was meant by pairing age of husband with age of male in household)
gen husband=0
bys hid: replace husband = 1 if husband_age_hid == HL6

*copy husbands education information to the whole household
gen husband_ED4 = ED4 if husband==1
bys hid: egen husb_educ=max(husband_ED4)

*data cleaning, if necessary
drop husband*
```

could be better to use tempvars instead of generating new variables in the first step, but thought these variables could be useful later.

Comment: Note that this is as much a sketch as real Stata code. For example, the `max()` calls are illegal, but using `egen` is the way forward. `if husband=1` needs `==` not `=`. As I've requested from the OP, a little dataset to play with would make things easier.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! As Nick mentioned, however, the `max()` command didn't work.. I have now included a sample of the dataset.

Comment: Nick is correct, as always. Made some corrections to the code. note it is as Nick says more of a sketch than finished code to show a possible way of going about this.

Comment: I see now that you have education as string variable. the `egen husb_educ = max(husband_ED4)` will fail. I recommend changing the education variable (and MA1) to numeric indicators with labels.

Comment: From the question we can't yet tell whether we are seeing strings or value labels.

Comment: All variables are numeric*

Comment: OK; then please show us a listing without labels, too.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the new information requested.